# How to ask 10 random math questions for a math quiz program for kids?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a math program for kids for a school project that asks 10 questions. I am having trouble finding out how and where to apply a loop in my code. I have tried to use for loop inside my enterbtnListener and startBtnListener but unfortunately none have work. This is the output of the program. [program_OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJp6f.jpg)

Here is the code of the startBtnListener

```
class startBtnListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (add.isSelected()) {
            ansBtn.setEnabled(true);
            input.setEditable(true);
            result = num1 + num2;
            question = ("What is " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " = ");

            questionTOP.setVisible(false);
            questionHERE.setText(question);
            questionHERE.setVisible(true);
            input.setVisible(true);

            add.setEnabled(false); //disables buttons until END button is clicked
            subtract.setEnabled(false);
            multiply.setEnabled(false);
            beginner.setEnabled(false);
            intermediate.setEnabled(false);
            advanced.setEnabled(false);


        } else if (subtract.isSelected()) {
            ansBtn.setEnabled(true);
            input.setEditable(true);
            result = num1 - num2;
            question = ("What is " + num1 + " - " + num2 + " = ");

            questionTOP.setVisible(false);
            questionHERE.setText(question);
            questionHERE.setVisible(true);
            input.setVisible(true);

            add.setEnabled(false); //disables buttons until END button is clicked
            subtract.setEnabled(false);
            multiply.setEnabled(false);
            beginner.setEnabled(false);
            intermediate.setEnabled(false);
            advanced.setEnabled(false);

        } else if (multiply.isSelected()) {
            ansBtn.setEnabled(true);
            input.setEditable(true);
            result = num1 * num2;
            question = ("What is " + num1 + " * " + num2 + " = ");

            questionTOP.setVisible(false);
            questionHERE.setText(question);
            questionHERE.setVisible(true);
            input.setVisible(true);

            add.setEnabled(false); //disables buttons until END button is clicked
            subtract.setEnabled(false);
            multiply.setEnabled(false);
            beginner.setEnabled(false);
            intermediate.setEnabled(false);
            advanced.setEnabled(false);

        } else {
            ansBtn.setEnabled(false);
            input.setEditable(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You need to choose below!", "PLEASE NOTE", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code of the enterBtnListener

```
class enterListener implements KeyListener {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            if (beginner.isSelected()) {
                num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
                num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
            } else if (intermediate.isSelected()) {
                num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 11);
                num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 11);
            } else if (advanced.isSelected()) {
                num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 17 + 13);
                num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 17 + 13);
            }

            // checking answer is correct or wrong
            while (true) {
                double doubleOfInput = Double.parseDouble(input.getText()); // getting string to double
                if (doubleOfInput == result) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "correct");
                    input.setText(" "); // clearing input after user entered answer
                    break;
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong, Try Again!");
                    input.setText(" ");
                }
            }

            //generating formula
            if (add.isSelected()) {
                result = num1 + num2;
                question = ("What is " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " = ");
            } else if (subtract.isSelected()) {
                result = num1 - num2;
                question = ("What is " + num1 + " - " + num2 + " = ");
            } else if (multiply.isSelected()) {
                result = num1 * num2;
                question = ("What is " + num1 + " * " + num2 + " = ");
            } else {
                result = num1 + num2;
                question = ("What is " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " = ");
            }

            questionHERE.setText(question);//setting new question
        }

    }
```

I would very much appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: is enterBtnListener used for the Answer button?

Comment: enterBtn Listener is for the "Enter" key when pressed, i also have an answerBtnListener which is for the Answer button. Both listeners however have identical codes because they should function the same in the program

Answer (score 1):

Looks good! My opinion would be to have a design where

1. A `start button` -> listener will initiate this math quiz.
2. A `next button` -> listener will have a iterate a class (instance level) variable and
   you can have it until it reaches your desired count (10 say)
3. An `End button` -> listener will terminate this math quiz and possibly should post the
   results. Possibly have this terminate and show result logic in a separate method and
   call here. (method name: terminateQuiz (say))

The next button whose listener will look roughly like,

```
class nextBtnListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //count++;
       //when count reaches 10 (say) it should call terminateQuiz
    }
}
```

All other things looks fine..

Note: Reason for Next button gives better look and feel than an enter key.

//Happy learning!

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried this method and noticed that it functions the same as my Answer button which shows the next question after the user have entered the correct answer. My problem is that I want only 10 questions to be asked in the program but my condition now, is it asks infinitely until the user hits the End button.

Comment: I'm not fully aware of your class, I suggested the next btn because they can even modify the answer and shd click answer again but that shd not be considered as a new question. New question can be controlled by a separate listener, but have you tried introducing a var at class level and iterate that in you answerBtn listener, so that you'll have the control over no. of times the que were asked?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your **enterListener** class is one which is handling **ANSWER** button for gui and flow is like below:

StartButton - will initialize the quiz and show the initial question
Answer Button - will accept the answer entered by user and will show next button.

So your loop may go like below in **enterListener**

```
class enterListener implements KeyListener {
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        if (beginner.isSelected()) {
            num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
            num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
        } else if (intermediate.isSelected()) {
            num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 11);
            num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 11);
        } else if (advanced.isSelected()) {
            num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 17 + 13);
            num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 17 + 13);
        }
        for(int i = 1 ; i < 10 ;i++){ //start your loop with 1 till 9 showing 9 questions as first one is already start with startbutton
            // checking answer is correct or wrong
            while (true) {
                double doubleOfInput = Double.parseDouble(input.getText()); // getting string to double
                if (doubleOfInput == result) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "correct");
                    input.setText(" "); // clearing input after user entered answer
                    break;
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong, Try Again!");
                    input.setText(" ");
                }
            }

            //generating formula
            if (add.isSelected()) {
                result = num1 + num2;
                question = ("What is " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " = ");
            } else if (subtract.isSelected()) {
                result = num1 - num2;
                question = ("What is " + num1 + " - " + num2 + " = ");
            } else if (multiply.isSelected()) {
                result = num1 * num2;
                question = ("What is " + num1 + " * " + num2 + " = ");
            } else {
                result = num1 + num2;
                question = ("What is " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " = ");
            }

            questionHERE.setText(question);//setting new question
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for replying, I have tried your suggestion but it keeps prompting many errors and the questions still are continuously showing unless the user clicks the End button.